# Show that $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts faithfully on the upper half plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

For some reason I am having a lot of trouble with this. I know that $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the upper half plane via Mobius transformations, i.e.
$$z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
where our matrix is made of $a,b,c,$ and $d$ from left to right, top to down.

To show that $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts faithfully, we need to show that the only matrices that act as the identity in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ are the scalar matrices corresponding to $1$ and $-1$. I am running into a little bit of a problem here. If we pick some matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix},$$
then I know that when $c=0$, it must be the case that $a=d$ and $b=0$, which implies that $a=d=1$ or $a=d=-1$. I am not precisely sure how to proceed in the general case, as I couldn't find a good way to use the fact that $\det(A)=1$.

Comment: If $\gamma(z)=z$ then  $\gamma(i\infty)=i\infty$ so $c=0$.

Comment: @reuns Is $i\infty$ and element of the upper half plane? Regardless, I think this works as I can argue that if $c\neq 0$, then we can take $|z|$ large enough such that $\gamma$ cannot be the identity. Thanks!